# Android Emulator not displaying data from php server

Tags: java, php, android

> Here is my code from android application [MainActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/HgnB1CN4)
>   [GetDatafromDB.java](http://pastebin.com/rf7pEhvk) [Users.java](http://pastebin.com/FS4B5Qqj)
>
> My problem is that, Data is supposed to be displayed in form of table
>   and emulator is able to display only header but not the data. Also no
>   error is generated either inside the app or in the logcat.
>
> I am using wamp server and it is working perfectly.
>
> here is my php code [stock.php](http://pastebin.com/ZKm73EQ1)

Comment: check that inernet connection is work or not in emulator and also check wamp server is start

Comment: Both of them are working properly. Also i did restart the wamp server. but still nothing is being displayed on my screen.

Comment: Have you stepped through it in a debugger?